# SQLite3 same .read file works in one session but not in next

Tags: sqlite, insert

I have prepared a huge list of sql statements (INSERT calls)s in a file which I run from sqlite3 terminal with

```
.read tmp/commands.sql
```

When I run the command one or more times in session #1 all goes well with no error and result as expected the ignore prevents against error messages for the duplicates).

Now if I quit sqlite3 with `.quit` then immediately come back and run the same command `.read tmp/commands.sql` I get for each sql call in my commands.sql an error message `"Error: near line xxx: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed"`

- My database is made of two tables with a relation
- a foreign key is defined in the second table to link to the fist one on its unique ID (FolderID)
- in the beginning of the sql script, I added `PRAGMA foreign_keys = true;` to I thought allow relations

Can you please explain why this is happening in the second session?

Thanks

---

### The first call in the commands.sql file will look like this

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = true;


/*
------------------------------------------------------------------
adding data in Folders for '0003_Runs/HiSeq2500/190921_7001450_0495_AH5JJ7BCX3
------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Folders 
  (
  Creator, 
  CreatorVersion, 
  DBAddDate, 
  FolderPath, 
  FolderName, 
  FolderSize, 
  Protection, 
  DeviceModel, 
  StartDate, 
  DeviceID, 
  RunNr, 
  FlowCellID, 
  ProjectNR, 
  Status, 
  DeliveryDate, 
  Comment
  )
VALUES (
  "AddIlluminaFolders2", 
  " 1.0; 2020-09-11", 
  "1600864879", 
  "0003_Runs/HiSeq2500", 
  "190921_7001450_0495_AH5JJ7BCX3", 
  "183173644288", 
  "0", 
  "HiSeq2500", 
  "190921", 
  "7001450", 
  "0495", 
  "AH5JJ7BCX3", 
  "", 
  "done", 
  "", 
  ""
  );

/*
------------------------------------------------------------------
adding data in Actions for 0003_Runs/HiSeq2500/190921_7001450_0495_AH5JJ7BCX3
------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Actions 
  (
  FolderID,
  Creator, 
  CreatorVersion, 
  ActionDate, 
  ActionName, 
  Comment
  )
VALUES (
  last_insert_rowid(),
  "AddIlluminaFolders2", 
  " 1.0; 2020-09-11", 
  "1600864879", 
  "AddIlluminaFolders2", 
  ""
  );

-- ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

followed by many other blocks of the same kind until end of file with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = true;`

[image: database schema]

### Here is my full table definition

```
/*
 Database structure for NCDataMngr and BigData_viewer
 Author: Stéphane Plaisance - VIB-Nucleomics Core
 database version: 1.0 - 2020-09-11
 File Encoding         : utf-8
 REM: edit below if you change the database schema
 => INSERT INTO "version" (vnum, vdate) VALUES ("1.0", "2020-09-11");
*/

PRAGMA foreign_keys = false;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for Folders
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Folders";
CREATE TABLE "Folders" (
     "FolderID" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     "Creator" TEXT(255,0),
     "CreatorVersion" TEXT(255,0),
     "DBAddDate" TEXT(255,0),
     "FolderPath" TEXT(255,0) NOT NULL,
     "FolderName" TEXT(255,0) NOT NULL,
     "FolderSize" INTEGER(20,0),
     "Protection" INTEGER(1,0),
     "DeviceModel" TEXT(255,0),
     "StartDate" TEXT(255,0),
     "DeviceID" TEXT(255,0),
     "RunNr" TEXT(255,0),
     "FlowCellID" TEXT(255,0),
     "ProjectNR" TEXT(255,0),
     "Status" TEXT(255,0),
     "DeliveryDate" TEXT(255,0),
     "Comment" TEXT(255,0)
);
INSERT INTO "main".sqlite_sequence (name, seq) VALUES ("Folders", '0');

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for Actions
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Actions";
CREATE TABLE "Actions" (
     "FolderID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
     "ActionID" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     "Creator" TEXT(255,0),
     "CreatorVersion" TEXT(255,0),
     "ActionDate" TEXT,
     "ActionName" TEXT(255,0),
     "Comment" TEXT(255,0),
    CONSTRAINT "Folders2Actions" FOREIGN KEY ("FolderID") REFERENCES "Folders" ("FolderID") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
INSERT INTO "main".sqlite_sequence (name, seq) VALUES ("Actions", '0');

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for version
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "version";
CREATE TABLE "version" (
     "vnum" text,
     "vdate" text
);
INSERT INTO "main".sqlite_sequence (name, seq) VALUES ("version", '0');
INSERT INTO "version" (vnum, vdate) VALUES ("1.1", "2020-09-23");

-- ----------------------------
--  View structure for ActionView
-- ----------------------------
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS "ActionView";
CREATE VIEW "ActionView" AS SELECT
Actions.*,
Folders.FolderName
FROM
Actions
INNER JOIN Folders ON Folders.FolderID = Actions.FolderID
ORDER BY
Actions.FolderID ASC,
Actions.ActionID ASC;

-- ----------------------------
--  View structure for FolderView
-- ----------------------------
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS "FolderView";
CREATE VIEW "FolderView" AS SELECT
Folders.*
FROM
Folders
ORDER BY
Folders.FolderID ASC;

-- ----------------------------
--  Indexes structure for table Folders
-- ----------------------------
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "idx_Folders_FolderPath_FolderName" on Folders ( "FolderPath", "FolderName" );

-- ----------------------------
--  Indexes structure for table Actions
-- ----------------------------
CREATE INDEX "idx_Actions_FolderID" ON Actions ("FolderID" ASC);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "idx_Actions_FolderID_Creator" ON Actions ("FolderID" ASC, "Creator");

PRAGMA foreign_keys = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last_insert_rowid(). When commands.sql is run mutliple times in the same session, `last_insert_rowid()` has the value of the last row inserted. Which will never give a FOREIGN KEY failure. When a new session is invoked, no rows are inserted (because of the "dupes"), `last_insert_rowid()` has value 0, thus FOREIGN KEY violation on Actions insert.

Comment: Thanks Dino, this makes sense.
When I now set the initial pragma to false, I do not get the warnings anymore. I thought that I needed this pragma line because my tables are related but I guess than when using the ```ast_insert_rowid()``` as key, I do not need relationality anymore during import. Is this the actual solution or should I better process these import differently (and support ignoring duplicates). This import should occur each day to pick up new folders added the day before so every day there will be a large majority of duplicates.

Comment: I think it needs a better design and/or process. If foreign_keys is false, `Actions.FoldersID` will get out of sync. The first so-called dupe Actions gets inserted with FoldersID = 0; the second Actions dupe gets inserted with FoldersID _of the last inserted Actions row_, which may or may not give FK violation, and likely will not attach it to the correct Folders row. Maybe FK on Folder path/name instead of ID?

Comment: Yes @DinoCoderSaurus, makes a lot of sense, actually I indexed path+name which I read was sufficient to avoid duplicated. It seems to work for me now but I will do some more testing to be sure. Thanks a lot for your advice, really helped me.